# Python, how come we can create class variables that were not defined in class creation?

Tags: python, class, instance-variables, class-variables

Let's say we have this simple Python code

```
class MyClass(object):
    class_var = 1

    def __init__(self, i_var):
        self.i_var = i_var
```

Correct me if I get any of this wrong:

Class_Var is a class variable that is the same for all instances of MyClass object.
I_Var is an instance variable that only exists in instances of the MyClass object

```
foo = MyClass(2)
bar = MyClass(3)

foo.class_var, foo.i_var
## 1, 2
bar.class_var, bar.i_var
## 1, 3
```

Class variables are also properties of the class itself.

```
MyClass.class_var ##
## 1
```

MyClass.I_var should error out, correct?

**Does that mean that class variables can be considered like instance variables of the class object itself (since all classes are objects) ?**

```
MyClass.new_attribute = 'foo'
print(hasattr(ObjectCreator, 'new_attribute'))
```

That should return true. And

```
print (MyClass.new_attribute)
```

should return foo.

How come we can create a new class variable that was not defined in the original definition for that class?

Is

```
MyClass.new_attribute = 'foo'
```

the exact same thing as creating that class attribute in the original definition?

```
class MyClass(object):
    class_var = 1
    new_attribute = 'foo'
```

So we can create new class attributes at runtime? How does that not interfere with the init constructor that creates the class object and has those class variables as instance variables of the class object?

Comment: Exactly. A `class` object is an instance of `type`, with `type` being referred to as the *metaclass* of `MyClass`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `class` object is just an instance of yet another type, usually `type` (though you can change this using the `metaclass` parameter to the `class` statement).

Like most other instances, you can add arbitrary instance attributes to a `class` object at any time.

Class attributes and instance attributes are wholly separate; the former are stored on the `class` object, the latter on instances of the class.

There's nothing particularly special about `__init__`; it's just another method that, among other things, can attached new attributes to an object. What *is* special is that `__init__` is called *automatically* when you create a new instance of the class by calling the class. `foo = MyClass(2)` is equivalent to

```
foo = MyClass.__new__(MyClass, 2)
foo.__init__(2)
```

The class statement

```
class MyClass(object):
    class_var = 1

    def __init__(self, i_var):
        self.i_var = i_var
```

is roughly equivalent to

```
def my_class_init(self, i_var):
    self.i_var = i_var


MyClass = type('MyClass', (object,), {'class_var': 1, '__init__': my_class_init})
```

The 3-argument form of `type` lets you pass a `dict` that creates class attributes when you first create the class, but you can always assign attributes after the fact as well:

```
MyClass = type('MyClass', (object,), {})
MyClass.class_var = 1
MyClass.__init__ = my_class_init
```

---

Just to blow your mind a *little* bit more, the call to `type` can be thought of as

```
MyClass = type.__new__(type, 'MyClass', (object,), {...})
MyClass.__init__('MyClass', (object,), {...})
```

though unless you define a custom metaclass (by subclassing `type`), you never have to think about `type` itself having `__new__` and `__init__` methods.

Comment: So when you do self.xyz = 1 in the init method, it is like you are adding class attributes to the instantiated object? Ah okay, and the attributes can be variables or methods.

Comment: Class attribute means something different in Python than it does in other languages. A class attribute is an attribute of a class. An instance attribute is an attribute of an instance of a class. Since a class *is* an instance of another class, `class_var` can be though of an instance attribute of an instance of `type`, or as a class attribute of the class `MyClass`.

Answer (score 0):

> Does that mean that class variables can be considered like instance variables of the class object itself (since all classes are objects) ?

Yes.

> How come we can create a new class variable that was not defined in the original definition for that class?

Because Python is a dynamic language. A class can be created at run time - in fact, it **is** created at run time when you run Python interactively.

> So we can create new class attributes at runtime?

Yes, unless the metaclass (the class of the class) has forbidden it.

> How does that not interfere with the init constructor that creates the class object and has those class variables as instance variables of the class object?

The only rule is that you cannot use something that has not yet be defined or something that has been deleted:

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
    class_var = 1

    def __init__(self, i_var):
        self.i_var = i_var
        self.j_var = self.class_var + 1


>>> a = MyClass(2)
>>> del MyClass.class_var
>>> b = MyClass(3)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#39>", line 1, in <module>
    b = MyClass(3)
  File "<pyshell#36>", line 6, in __init__
    self.j_var = self.class_var + 1
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'class_var'
```

There is no magic here: anything can only exists between its definition point and its destruction point. Python allows you to add attributes to objects at any time, except that some classes (for example `object`) forbid it.

With the previous `a` object of class `MyClass`, you could do:

```
a.z_var = 12
```

from that point, `z_var` will be an attribute of `a` but others objects of same class will not have it.

Simply `object` forbids that:

```
>>> o = object()
>>> o.x=1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#41>", line 1, in <module>
    o.x=1
AttributeError: 'object' object has no attribute 'x'
```